# Trace of a product of a recursive series of non-full rank matrices

Tags: matrices, trace, pattern-recognition

Let $H$ be a $m\times n$ matrix that is *not* full rank. Hence $H^T H \neq \mathbb{1}_{m\times m}$. Can we say anything about the diagonal entries, or the trace, of matrix products of the form:

$P_0 = H^T H$

$P_1 = H^T(H^T H)H$

$P_2 = H^T(H^T(H^T H)H)H$

$\vdots$

$P_n = H^T P_{n-1} H$

Can we estimate the trace of $P_n$ as a function of $n$ ?

*Context: This is unrelated as such to the question, but If anyone is curious:*

The matrix $H$ to which I want to apply the above result is the parity check matrix for a linear code. The adjacency matrix of the tanner graph which describes the linear code is simply:

$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0_{m\times m} & H \\ H^T & 0_{n\times n} \end{pmatrix}$

and $A^2$ can be expressed as

$A^2 = \begin{pmatrix} H H^T & 0_{n\times n} \\ 0_{n\times n} & H^T H \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} P^T_0 & 0_{n\times n} \\ 0_{n\times n} & P_0 \end{pmatrix}$

and more generally

$A^{2^{(n+1)}} = \begin{pmatrix} P^T_n & 0_{n\times n} \\ 0_{n\times n} & P_n \end{pmatrix}$

If the trace of the above matrix is $\text{Tr}(A^{2^{(n+1)}})$, then it is equal to the number of cycles in the Tanner graph of length $2^{(n+1)}$. It is this quantity that I want to comment about.

Comment: Addition: $\text{Tr}(P_n) = \text{Tr}(P^T_0 P_{n-1})$ by cyclic property of trace.

Comment: According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices) we can say: $\text{Tr}(P_n) = \sum_{i,j}[P_0]_{i,j}[P_{(n-1)}]_{i,j}$, i.e, an element-wise product of $P_0$ and $P_{(n-1)}$, but I am interested if it can be some function of the rank of $H$ or $n$ ?

Comment: Pavithran, you write nonsense. Since $H^TH$ is a $n\times n$ matrix (and not, as you write a $m\times m$ matrix), $P_1$ is not defined ! The last but not the least, if $P_0=H^TH$, then $P_0^T=H^TH\not= HH^T$.